# infinite vector space, derivative formula

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm presuming to make a major **edit**. The question as asked is badly garbled, and will likely be closed. That would be too bad, because the *actual* question in interesting and useful. Hence this revision.

**Original**, as incorrectly corrected:

How would you show that, given the infinite vector space entitled $V$ : $C^\infty ( \mathbb{R} , \mathbb{C} )$, and the endomorphism that associate to a function its derivative named D, that :

$$\forall f \in V : e^\lambda D^n ( e^{-\lambda} f ) = (D - \lambda Id_V ) ^n (f) $$

[**Comment:** It's not clear here whether $e^\lambda$ is supposed to be a constant, or we're regarding $\lambda$ as the variable and differentiating with respect to $\lambda$. But with either interpretation the assertion is simply false.]

I have no clue at all.

Thank you

**Edit:** The actual question is this:

> > For each scalar $\lambda$ define a function $e_\lambda$ by $e_\lambda(t)=e^{\lambda t}$. Show that $e_\lambda D^n(e_{-\lambda}f)=(D-\lambda I)^nf$.

(How do I know that's what the question was supposed to be? It's the same as the *original* original, except with a definition of $e_\lambda$ provided; the definition is perfectly natural, and makes the assertion both correct and interesting. Also the revised version is a standard and in  some sense well known fact: For $n=1$ the identity is just an "abstract" or "operator-theoretic" formulation of the standard algorithm for solving the differential equation $y'-\lambda y=g$. If the idea that the OP would consistently write $e^\lambda$ in place of $e^{\lambda t}$ semms implausible I conjecture you've  never taught differential equations...)

Comment: What are $e_\lambda$ and $e_{-\lambda}$?

Comment: they are the exponentials with the argument $\lambda$. We are in the space of functions

Comment: If they are exponentials, then why didn't you write them as $e^\lambda$ and $e^{-\lambda}$?

Comment: it s corrected :)

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: but maybe there is another method ? I don't understand from where the exponential come from

Comment: If you have a differential equation $(D-\lambda I)y=0$, do you understand where the exponential in the solution comes from?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Actually she's wrong about what $e_\lambda$ is. In fact $e_\lambda$ is the exonential _function_ defined by $e_\lambda(t)=e^{\lambda t}$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich But I understood that, that's why I said that I'm talking about the exponential in the space of the functions... sorry I thought that this kind of expression if sufficient to itself :/

Comment: @ProfessorVector Is it from integrating both side with the LHS y'/y ? but how do you solve the case n =2?

Comment: Aargh. No, the expression $e^\lambda$ is not the same as the expression $e^{\lambda t}$. Saying you're talking about the exponential  in the space of functions doesn't make them the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original  version of the question failed to define the notation $e_\lambda$. Curiously, the "correction" got the definition totally wrong.

The actual question is this:

> > For each scalar $\lambda$ define a function $e_\lambda$ by $e_\lambda(t)=e^{\lambda t}$. Show that $e_\lambda D^n(e_{-\lambda}f)=(D-\lambda I)^nf$.

In other words, if we let $m_\lambda$ denote the operation "multiply by $e_\lambda$", or $$(m_\lambda f)(t)=e^{\lambda t}f(t),$$the question is

> > Show that $(D-\lambda I)^n$ is "similar" to $D^n$, in particular $(D-\lambda I)^n=m_\lambda D^n m_\lambda^{-1}$.

For $n=1$ this is just the product rule:$$e^{\lambda t}\frac d{dt}(e^{-\lambda t}f(t))=e^{\lambda t}(e^{-\lambda t}f'(t)-\lambda e^{-\lambda t}f(t))=f'(t)-\lambda f(t).$$

Hence for any natural number $n$ we have $$(D-\lambda I)^n=(m_\lambda Dm_\lambda^{-1})^n=m_\lambda D^n m_\lambda^{-1}.$$

Comment: but I don't understand the case n=2... could you do one more step please :)?

Comment: $(D-\lambda I)(D-\lambda I)=(m_\lambda Dm_\lambda^{-1})(m_\lambda D m_\lambda^{-1})=m_\lambda D(m_\lambda^{-1}m_\lambda )D m_\lambda^{-1}=m_\lambda D^2m_\lambda^{-1}$.

Comment: Your operations are strange... I ve never seen something like that.  You are allowed  to do so?  I mean, when you move the parenthesis, don t you have to derivate something? Nevertheless thanks to this messge i ve understood the formula so thank you  =)

Comment: I'm not sure what you think the problem is. Possibly what you're misunderstanding is this: Through the whole thing when I write $TS$ that means the _composition_ of the linear operators $T$ and $S$. So for example $Dm_\lambda$ is not the derivative of $m_\lambda$, it is $D\circ m_\lambda$. So yes, I can move the parentheses like that - composition of any sorts of functions is associative.

Comment: okay I understand thank you